# Best visible content extractor available

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping, html-content-extraction

So my application needs visible content from a given URL, like just the text part, no html no header or footer data. As of now I am using [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) and [boilerpipe](https://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe) for getting the same. But in some rare cases I am not getting enough data or the right data. So was wondering is there any other competitor, programming language is not a barrier.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `xpath` or `css` extractors directly for content extraction, both selectors are already simply implemented on [`parsel`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel) module.

For a complete suite of web-crawling + content extractor, [`scrapy`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy) would be my preferred option.

And if you want to extract to visually select what parts of the html to extract, I would recommend [`portia`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia).

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And yeah, all these are good, but we don't a crawler. Just need the visible content extraction form a page, like boilerpipe or beautifulsoup..